# Disabled input fields not changing text color with CSS in Jquery Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, disabled-input

I have some disabled input text fields that I want the text color to be black because it's too greyed out.

I know its a simple one-line code but it won't work for some reason. 
Other CSS properties work while it's disabled like the background color and stuff but not the text color.

**Here's the CSS:**

```
input[type="text"]:disabled {
  color: black;
}
```

**Here's the HTML:**

```
<div class="form-container">

                <label for="name">Full Name:</label>
                <input id="profileName" type="text" disabled="disabled">

                <label for="email">Email ID:</label>
                <input id="profileEmail" type="text" disabled="disabled">

                <label for="address">Address Line:</label>
                <input id="profileAddress" type="text" disabled="disabled">

                <label for="city">City:</label>
                <input id="profileCity" type="text" disabled="disabled">

                <label for="postcode">Postcode:</label>
                <input id="profilePostcode" type="text" disabled="disabled">

                <label for="state">State:</label>
                <input id="profileState" type="text" disabled="disabled">
</div>
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF3PS.png) is what it looks like on the android emulator running API 28.

I'm not sure why other properties work but not the text color.
Any ideas?

P.S. this is a cordova project and i am building it in **Jquery Mobile v1.4.5**

Comment: did you try giving `background: #fff;` ?

Comment: If the inputs are disabled, then how inputs are filled up as per your link https://i.stack.imgur.com/gF3PS.png

Comment: @NidhinJoseph I don't want the background to be white. I want the text color to change to black

Comment: @Kevin They're auto filled from my database.

Comment: @ShaneD'Silva Please see the answers once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice to reply to you about the issue you are facing.

Since, you are using Jquery Mobile. The Jquery mobile on DOM generates `div` covering the input box. Since, you are also using `disabled` property of input box. So, jquery mobile implements a `class` on that `div` and there the `opacity` level have been defined.

So, add this:-

```
.form-container .ui-input-text.ui-state-disabled { opacity:1; color:black; }
```

**Working Fiddle :-** https://jsfiddle.net/h3Lbadgv/1/

Hope it works for you.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work for me. I'm stumped

Comment: It works with other colors but not black. Why is this?

Comment: Can you build a proper fiddle of your issue, so I can test it from my end properly..

Comment: also, are you using jquery mobile API?

Comment: Yes, I'm using JQuery Mobile 1.4.5 js and 1.11.1 css

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9815kuae/3/ Here's the fiddle but the JQM isn't working

Comment: check my answer above @shane.

Comment: Thanks, mate. Saved me from pulling my hair out.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use this one.

```css
.form-container input:disabled{color: black}
```

```html
<div class="form-container">

                <label for="name">Full Name:</label>
                <input value="XXXPPPAAPP" id="profileName" type="text" disabled="disabled">

                <label for="email">Email ID:</label>
                <input value="XXXPPPAAPP" id="profileEmail" type="text" disabled="disabled">

                <label for="address">Address Line:</label>
                <input value="XXXPPPAAPP" id="profileAddress" type="text" disabled="disabled">

                <label for="city">City:</label>
                <input value="XXXPPPAAPP" id="profileCity" type="text" disabled="disabled">

                <label for="postcode">Postcode:</label>
                <input id="profilePostcode" type="text" disabled="disabled">

                <label for="state">State:</label>
                <input id="profileState" type="text" disabled="disabled">
</div>
```

Hope It Helps.

Comment: That weirdly changed my labels to red.

Comment: It shouldn't affect labels though!! Look at the snippet once. Can you confirm that the css you copy is the same?

Comment: try to add this `.form-container input:disabled{color: black}`

Comment: I did but it doesn't work with black. Please see edit in my question

Comment: Try this once.  `form-container input:disabled{color: black !important; opacity:1}`

Comment: Still no. The opacity doesn't do anything either

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200749/discussion-between-kevin-and-shane-dsilva).